# ¿Cómo Deserializar un json en sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

He estado intentando Deserializar un json en sql, el json está guardado en una columna de una tabla, JSON_VALUE me permite realizar la consulta en la tabla y en esa columna:

```
SELECT top 100 JSON_VALUE(Respuesta, '$.message') as 'columna'
from BitacoraNotificaciones
WHERE IdProceso = 14
AND
Exitoso = 0
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

como resultado da los datos de la columna es decir el json :[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al querer navegar y extraer los datos dentro de ese json me da error :

```
SELECT top 100 JSON_VALUE(Respuesta, '$.message.Skus') as 'columna'
from BitacoraNotificaciones
WHERE IdProceso = 14
AND
Exitoso = 0
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

nota:

```
{
    "name": "builtins.Exception",
    "message": "{'Skus': [{'Sku': '157223', 'Mensaje': 'No hay suficiente disponibilidad en la Bodega'}], 'Bodegas': [], 'TiendasDestino': []}",
    "code": 500
}
```

los valones "Skus","Bodegas" y "TiendasDestino" son los valores los cuales quiero leer

Comment: ¿Y cómo fue guardado el campo? Es decir, ¿qué valor tiene? Por cierto, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: haz intentado guardarlo en una variable nvarchar y tratarlo como json puro? usando openjson()?

Comment: Te recomendaría almacenar el resultado en una variable y posteriormente utilizar [openjson()](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-parse-json-in-sql-server/)

Comment: Podrías por favor, [edit] e incluir en tu pregunta el valor de prueba que intentas navegar con esa consulta?